# Controller in com_(name)/somecontroller.php not used

Tags: php, joomla, classloader, joomla1.5

I'm trying to implement the `task` get parameter in my Joomla application but it's kind of hard since I just found out the controller in com_(name)/(viewname).php isn't used at all.

For example; I have the following url:

/index.php?option=com_mymodule&view=game&format=text&task=savescore&layout=savegamesresult&id=1216

It works fine but the parameter `task` may as well not be there, the file `/public_html/components/com_mymodule/controllers/game.php` may as well not be there either. I'm trying to use a specific model for this specific task but since Joomla is ignoring the controller it's kind of hard.

This is the content of the game.php controller:

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// import Joomla controller library
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

class mymoduleControllergame extends JController
     function __construct()
           {
              parent::__construct();
              $this->registerTask( 'savescore' );
           }
     function display($tpl=null)
        {
            JRequest::setVar('view','nonexistingonethatshouldgivemeanerror');
            $model=$this->getModel('game');
            $view = $this->getView();
            $view->setModel($model,true);
            parent::display($tpl);
        }
    function savescore(){
        JRequest::setVar('view','game');
        $model=$this->getModel('anothermodel');
        $view = $this->getView();
        $view->setModel($model,true);
        parent::display($tpl);
    }
}
```

Opening the url gives me the view called game using the default model, no error and no task. Somehow the controller is not picked up. Model and view are used based on the naming convention I assume and I assume that the controller is so too but maybe I'm missing a parameter in the url that would specify what **controller** and **task** to use since the controller can set up what view and layout to use (if not provided).

I am using Joomla 1.5

Answer (score 0):

In /public_html/components/mycomponent/mycomponent.php I added:

```
if($controller = JRequest::getVar('controller'))
{
 require_once(JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'controllers'.DS.$controller.'.php');
}
else
{
 require_once(JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'controller.php');
}
$classname = 'mycomponentController'.$controller;
$controller = new $classname(JRequest::getVar('task', ''));
$controller->execute(JRequest::getVar('task', ''));
$controller->redirect();
```

Had to change /public_html/components/com_mycomponent/controllers/game.php a little to:

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
// import Joomla controller library
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');
class mycomponentControllerfame extends JController{
     function __construct()
           {
              parent::__construct();
              $this->registerTask( 'savescore','savescore' );
           }
     function display($tpl=null)
        {
            JRequest::setVar('view','game');
            $model=$this->getModel('game');
            $view = $this->getView('game','text');
            $view->setModel($model,true);
            parent::display($tpl);
        }
    function savescore(){
        JRequest::setVar('view','game');
        JRequest::setVar('model','tournament');
        $model=$this->getModel('tournament');
        $view = $this->getView('game','text');
        $view->setModel($model,true);
        $view->setLayout('savegamesresult');
        $view->display();
    }
}
```

It's executing the savescore and using the right model, view and layout.